# Returning the Post Slug

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible for me return the `Post Url` attached to a custom taxonomy on WordPress?

I have done something like this.

```
$taxonomy = 'series';
$tax_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );
print_r($tax_terms);
```

how ever this only returns the following.

```
[0] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 7447 [name] => episode [slug] => episode [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 7447 [taxonomy] => series [description] => [parent] => 0
```

I need to return the actual post pages which have that taxonomy included on them, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you're looking for is `get_term_link()` - here's the Codex page that explains it: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/